# How to make a launcher(.desktop file) for a binary file?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, .desktop

I have sccceded in making launchers with python scripts,php scripts,etc as launchers.

Now I want to make a binary file as a launcher. It is not an installable binary file. It is actually the binary file for WorldOfGoo. The filename is **WorldOfGoo.bin32**. On runing this file from terminal by the command `./WorldOfGoo.bin32` the game starts.

when i added the path to this file in the **Exec** field in the **[Desktop Entry]**, like this

> /path/to/folder/and/then/WorldOfGoo.bin32 *

and when I clicked on the desktop file,it says **"Permission Denied"**

How do i get a binary file to work in a .desktop file?

Comment: Permission Denied would normally say that you should `chmod +x WorldOfGoo.bin32`. Is it a typo or are you using "./path/to/folder/and/then/WorldOfGoo.bin32" (with the leading dot) in the Exec field?

Comment: you have to make sure that the binary file as well as the .desktop file have executable permissions

Comment: Why should .desktop file have executable permissions? isnt it just a plain text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example - it starts `xnview.sh`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=0
Exec=/home/pierre/Desktop/XnViewMP/xnview.sh
Icon=/home/pierre/Desktop/XnViewMP/xnview.png
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;
StartupNotify=true
Name=XnView Multi Platform
GenericName=XnViewMP
```

**Edit**:

If You have a nasty complex command to be run - put it all in script and run the script. For example if You have to cd there first, and run the script from there make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /to/YourDir
./YourBinaryFile
```

Comment: its not workin...i mean the game starts but just exits within a second..!!

Comment: Try to add ampersand after the shell command. How does it work - if You'll just run the binary from the shell?

Comment: Oh I see it in Your question - You can start the thing from terminal. You can then put `Exec=gnome-terminal -e '/path/to...'` or `Exec=konsole -e '/path/to...'` if You are using KDE.

Comment: nope...it still exits..this happens even for a simple softlink of that file you know...even that does not work...its like u have to go to the particular folder and then only ude it!

Comment: If You have to go there - it's not a problem: `Exec=cd /to/Your/Folder; ./YourBinary`

Comment: does not work...:( it says- `Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Still it's not a problem - just make a bash script: `#!/bin/bash; cd /to/Your/Folder; ./YourBinary`, and give Exec the path of the bash script (don't forget to make the bash script executable).

Comment: aha! that worked! Plz post the last thing as the answer as that has worked..!! i'll accept it! ;)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

1. Make *.sh file home folder.
   Make it executable.
   Change your user name to your own (`.sh` and `.desktop` file):

   `nano qtwaifu2x.sh`

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /home/user/git/build-qtwaifu2x-Desktop-Debug
    ./qtwaifu2x
   ```
2. Make desktop files (`qtwaifu2x.desktop`)

   `nano qtwaifu2x.desktop`

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.1
    Name=Qtwaifu2x
    Comment=Image Super-Resolution for Anime-Style Art
    Exec=/home/user/qtwaifu2x.sh
    Icon=qtwaifu2x
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    Categories=Graphics;ImageProcessing;
   ```
3. Copy `qtwaifu2x.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications`
4. Copy `qtwaifu2x.png + svg` to `/usr/share/icons`
5. Use `slink /usr/share/applications/qtwaifu2x.desktop` to my desktop.
6. Desktop icon -> right click menu -> enable startup

...and done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `alacarte`, it is a user-friendly tool to create .desktop files. You can install it: `sudo apt install alacarte`.