# New App doesn't appear in Unity dash

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I have copied an executable in /usr/bin a program that I'd like to use.

Of course I can launch it with the command line. However it doesn't appear in Unity when I open the dash, and I would like to add it.

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a description, in a `.desktop` file, under the `~/.local/share/applications` directory.

E.g. `newprog.desktop` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/NEWPROG
Hidden=false
Name=My-Fancy-Name
Comment=Something I never want to say :-)
```

Comment: You have a typo: apllications, instead of applications. Also, need to add the point that it should have the .desktop filename to work correctly. Maybe we could also make the point that you can add categories that will make the search lens work better, and the file can be dragged to the launcer to lock it there.

Comment: I added the .desktop part, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `.desktop` file for your program (see [How to make a launcher(.desktop file) for a binary file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154060/how-to-make-a-launcher-desktop-file-for-a-binary-file)) and put in into `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Maybe the most simple way to do this is to use [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/)