# How can I create a launcher and also have it in the apps toolbar

Tags: unity, launcher, git

I want an app icon for smart git.

I can create one on my desktop with

```
$ gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/ --create-new
```

[image]

and selecting the smartgit.sh app.  That works for an icon on the desktop.

How can I move that icon / create a new one in my applications toolbar (so not just on the desktop)?

In my case that is the Unity applications toolbar (which I've moved to the left).

I've tried dragging and dropping it there but it didn't work.

I can make it appear in the dash home by adding an entry this way [New App doesn't appear in Unity dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191919/new-app-doesnt-appear-in-unity-dash)  but I still can't move it to be an app icon in the apps toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Just run add-menuitem.sh on bin folder: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185222/smartgit-installation-and-usage-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the `.desktop` file you have created to `~/.local/share/applications`.

After that the application should appear in the dash search results when you search for an associated keyword (name, comment, etc.). From there just drag and drop it to the launcher like you would do with any other application.

In the future you might want to consider editing the main menu directly. You can do so with a menu editor like `alacarte` or `menulibre`:

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Alternatively you can configure the *create a launcher* dialogue to directly save the new   launchers in the right directory:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new
```

Comment: There's no applications folder under my ~/.local/share folder. I'm on a brand new installation, what to do?

Comment: Just create it yourself. The system will recognize any `.desktop` files in that location as application launchers.