# Create an icon in Dash panel?

Tags: unity-dash

I wonder how to create an icon on Dash panel on the left side of the desktop, to run the following combination of two commands

```
killall nautilus
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus
```

My Ubuntu is 12.04.

Thanks!

Comment: you might find this useful as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192286/how-can-i-create-a-launcher-and-also-have-it-in-the-apps-toolbar/192291#192291

Answer (score 7):

1) Create *.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/`

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/NAME OF LAUNCHER.desktop
```

2) Paste below text

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=ICON
Name=NAME OF LAUNCHER
Exec=killall nautilus && UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus
```

3) Change ICON to your icon path.

4) Change NAME OF LAUNCHER to the name you want.

5) Save the file and exit.

6) This will create a launcher in the dash. Click on the dash and search for the launcher name. Then drag the launcher to the bar to pin it.

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable working with root privileges and/or want the launcher to only be available to your user, you can use `gedit ~/.local/share/applications` instead of 1).

Comment: Thanks! (1) Where are default icons in 12.04? I want to reuse some. (2) "Change NAME OF LAUNCHER to the name you want." What does "NAME OF LAUNCHER" mean?