# How do I give my python shell an icon after I lock it to the unity laucher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I wanted fast access to my python shell, so I locked it to the launcher, but the icon is just a question mark, which I assume means it doesn't have the necessary file. For the sake of aesthetics, I would like to give it one, but I can't figure out how to. That is, I don't know what directory I should put it in, what type it should be (though I suspect .png) or what size (will it resize an oversized image to fit? or crop? or just mess up my dock?).

edit: grammar

Comment: make desktop file, `chmod +x` it and after that lock it to launcher i guess.

Comment: I think it must be in `/usr/share/icons/`, and *.png*

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help. At first keep icon in **/usr/share/icons/blah.png**.

And after that make a desktop launcher. More about that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154060/how-to-make-a-launcher-desktop-file-for-a-binary-file).

And just lock your **.desktop** file there instead of your script.

**OR** use Unity API ? For info [click here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/launcher/)