# Desktop shortcut or Add to Favourites 22.04

Tags: 22.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

I searched a bit but was unable to find a reliable answer. Is there any method to add shortcuts to an AppImage or anything similar to the desktop or the dock? Say, I downloaded Firefox directly from Mozilla, it is neither Snap nor deb, but a " click and use " file to launch. Can we add a shortcut to it on the desktop or to the dock as a favourite?

I am using 22.04. Thanks.

Comment: Search for how to make a desktop file in Ubuntu in your favorite search engine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a launcher(.desktop file) for a binary file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154060/how-to-make-a-launcher-desktop-file-for-a-binary-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering AppImage Files as a desktop app](https://askubuntu.com/q/902672/)

Comment: It is easier to create a .desktop file or a symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like creating a desktop shortcut is fairly simple in 22.04

For an AppImage in the `Downloads` folder, I used

```
ln -s /home/myPC/Downloads/GIMP_AppImage-git-2.10.25-20210401-withplugins-x86_64.AppImage /home/myPC/Desktop/GIMP2.10.25
```

No need to run this command from any folder. Start a Terminal and run the command based on the location of the AppImage and the location and name of the shortcut you want to use.

The following resources have more info, but I guess the above command adds a symbolic link very easily to the Desktop or others. I had to right click and use " Run as a Program " as Double click was not working

https://adamtheautomator.com/appimage-ubuntu/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXZma0t0PKE